# $http GET URL changes and looks for wrong resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I'm developing a single page application. I am making use of Angularjs.v1.2.28. I'm making a HTTP GET request to the backend using this code.

```
return {
        getCategories : function(sessionid,terminalid,tableno,section){

            var req = {
                     method: 'GET',
                     url: Config.url+ "/menucategories",
                     params : {
                         'sessionid' : sessionid,
                         'terminalid' : terminalid, 
                         'tableno' : tableno,
                         'section' : section
                     }
            };

            return $http.get(req);
        },
```

I make use of the promise object that is returned from service in controller.

```
var categoryPromise = categoryService.getCategories(sessionid,terminalid,tableno,section);
    categoryPromise.then(function(payload){
        var categories =  payload.data;

        if(categories.status.code == "1"){
            if(Object.prototype.toString.call(categories) === '[object Array]') {
                $scope.categories = categories;
                categoryService.setCategories(categories);
                $scope.pax = tableService.getPax();
                $scope.tablechair = tableService.getChoseTableChair();
            }
        }
        else{
            $location.url("/login");
            $scope.errorMsg = categories.status.desc;
        }
    },function(errorPayload){
        $location.url("/login");
        $scope.errorMsg = "Server error while processing the request.Please contact system administrator";
    });
```

It's always the errorCallback is getting called due to the URL getting changed to the browser application URL appended with some malformed characters. The URL which i give is

```
http://localhost:8080/CafexRestful/menucategories
```

But, it gets changed to the browser application URL below

```
http://localhost:8080/CafexMobile/[object%20Object]
```

I have been debugging in Chrome and Firebug. I couldn't resolve it. It may be something which is happening under the hood. The same code is working with another controller and service, where i fetch a different data. Please let me know if you need anymore information. Thanks.

Comment: What config.url returning you?

Comment: @mohamedrias It returns  'http://localhost:8080/CafexRestful'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$http.get** in angularjs needs an url string. You should use url string instead of an object

**Using $http.get function:**

```
  return {
            getCategories : function(){

                return $http.get("/menucategories"); // using $http.get function.
            },
```

**Using $http function.**

```
return {
        getCategories : function(sessionid,terminalid,tableno,section){

            var req = {
                     method: 'GET',
                     url: Config.url+ "/menucategories",
                     params : {
                         'sessionid' : sessionid,
                         'terminalid' : terminalid, 
                         'tableno' : tableno,
                         'section' : section
                     }
            };

            return $http(req); //using $http function only.
        },
```

Please see the document:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: The same code works in the another service. I will give a try.

Comment: Chances are your other services is `$http(req)`, which takes an object, rather than `$http.get(req)`, which takes a url string

Comment: Great, You saved my day. I have been coding without good eyes. Thanks